# Google showing SSL error message

Tags: .net, ssl, windows-server-2008

my client is getting the follow message from Google.

*Site host name, https://abc.meusite.com, does not match your SSL certificate Subject Name
We have noticed that the host name of your site, https://abc.meusite.com, does not match any of the "Subject Names" in your SSL certificate, which were:
secured.meusite.com
As a result, many web browsers will block users from accessing your site, or display a security warning message when your site is accessed.
Recommended action
To correct this problem, please get a new SSL certificate by a Certificate Authority (CA) with a "Subject Name" or "Subject Alternative DNS Names" that matches your host name.*

I notice that I can add alternative names to the certificate however this url doesn't use SSL. It's http://abc.meusite.com the user is putting the "s".

What I need to do to google stop send alert messages?

**Windows Server 2008, IIS 7 e .NET 3.5**

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused, because since a few days Google tries if SSL versions exist for all the sites registered in Google Webmaster Tools.

If you host SSL and non-SSL sites on the same IP and Google now requests https://www.never-meant-for-ssl.com/, your webserver (every make and model) will respond with one of the websites that support SSL on that IP (usually the first).

I don't think this is something to worry about. Its just Google blindly trying SSL on all websites, even those that don't have certificates.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure HTTPS connections to redirect to HTTP in your web.config file.

However, the presence of an SSL certificate at all indicates that there may be something worth securing on the site.  If that is the case, the better approach would be to add the Subject Alternative Name(s), and redirect in the other direction from HTTP to HTTPS.

You can add the following to web.config to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (and reverse mentions of http and https in that snippet for the other direction)

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Eric J. got the redirect problem. From OpenSSL's s_client, here are the problems with your certificate.

- Subject: CN=www.parkingcrew.com ... - don't use the CN for DNS names
- `www.parkingcrew.com` is just plain wrong
- Missing a SANs: `abc.meusite.com`

Apparently, your certificate should also have `secured.meusite.com` as a SAN.

So your certificate should have at least three SANs. And you also answer at `www`, so make that four. (In addition to the removal of the DNS CN and incorrect DNS name).

- `meusite.com`
- `www.meusite.com`
- `abc.meusite.com`
- `secured.meusite.com`

Here's the output from `s_client`:

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect abc.meusite.com:443 -servername abc.meusite.com 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            61:29:f1:07:8e:b3:c6:7f:68:89:fd:3c:e4:29:32:83
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Thawte, Inc., OU=Domain Validated SSL, CN=Thawte DV SSL CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 10 00:00:00 2014 GMT
            Not After : Jul  1 23:59:59 2017 GMT
        Subject: OU=Go to https://www.thawte.com/repository/index.html, OU=Thawte SSL123 certificate, OU=Domain Validated, CN=www.parkingcrew.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:c7:ef:c5:98:53:37:92:91:90:12:4f:46:0f:45:
                    a2:85:85:e7:27:cb:97:4f:2d:84:f6:0c:7a:9e:71:
                    06:d5:14:3d:43:55:b4:9f:4e:f9:11:9b:49:ec:74:
                    df:08:0b:30:2a:17:95:03:93:43:47:59:5f:ba:02:
                    00:0f:9c:b0:89:76:4e:4e:07:b5:59:42:f7:83:1f:
                    25:63:5c:b3:1e:60:77:f9:73:95:06:b8:d7:6c:b7:
                    01:e3:49:e3:02:6b:09:b1:74:e7:39:2a:0e:24:86:
                    f9:2d:39:0a:7a:06:e2:7c:80:ce:f6:67:5a:e6:13:
                    77:a9:1c:d5:c6:76:b8:6b:cd:7b:1c:2a:73:f4:80:
                    68:69:06:5b:e7:0a:83:0d:fc:97:ce:f7:17:55:ed:
                    32:cc:fd:ea:ad:8d:82:0f:dd:d4:b2:99:6d:9a:5f:
                    a6:ef:7b:b4:62:eb:3e:3a:b7:43:e6:d7:59:dd:f1:
                    59:e6:87:95:ea:25:80:29:90:58:6e:d1:61:55:e2:
                    03:ba:47:f9:b1:f9:18:a5:47:8e:69:77:b1:39:dc:
                    73:24:28:1b:95:c3:db:2d:2c:f6:ca:8c:7f:71:9b:
                    b0:db:bf:46:17:90:db:49:38:d4:24:c2:c1:e9:44:
                    a2:ba:a0:8e:1a:4f:a4:e5:f8:af:3c:77:c5:1b:38:
                    8d:1b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.parkingcrew.com
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://svr-dv-crl.thawte.com/ThawteDV.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54
                  CPS: https://www.thawte.com/cps

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:AB:44:E4:5D:EC:83:C7:D9:C0:85:9F:F7:E1:C6:97:90:B0:8C:3F:98

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.thawte.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://svr-dv-aia.thawte.com/ThawteDV.cer

    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         8d:1e:d9:92:2d:1f:b3:aa:61:d2:3b:31:ac:ec:de:18:18:4e:
         cb:52:13:f9:b7:ff:bc:95:8d:67:6d:3e:e7:3f:78:7f:2c:13:
         a8:9e:04:91:8b:40:47:db:38:60:5d:48:e1:1f:49:ad:20:6e:
         5c:51:05:ad:61:dc:dd:10:7a:61:d5:dd:ef:66:8b:5f:cb:5c:
         2b:b9:8a:ed:dd:4b:c2:14:b2:b0:4b:6e:64:c1:09:8e:2e:aa:
         80:b1:56:32:1c:d3:bd:94:30:18:16:c9:c0:7e:5c:c7:f0:ee:
         05:60:77:eb:ff:81:98:ff:8d:d6:f9:95:40:9e:0a:da:8b:d3:
         64:2c:80:55:4d:d1:a1:06:e9:58:02:32:02:96:d4:ba:b9:12:
         11:06:0a:1d:d9:ca:76:95:a5:b0:c9:86:21:8a:41:cf:d9:8a:
         11:57:5d:da:cd:3c:27:19:93:b2:50:1d:ed:fb:74:57:0e:32:
         58:5d:5e:72:6d:13:5a:81:2a:ce:2e:bf:8c:d1:18:64:0d:e4:
         c1:98:33:4e:28:46:3a:84:d2:fd:5e:0b:ff:dc:ac:f6:69:a9:
         06:ec:83:bc:75:d1:51:da:14:ca:12:a1:d4:1a:9a:9d:05:da:
         5b:4c:ec:64:62:c3:43:38:35:3e:30:2d:25:90:8a:4f:5a:d5:
         cd:e0:13:7d
```